# JOOQ: Update column values on null values

Tags: java, sql, jooq

I need to update the value of an integer column associated with a row using JOOQ on Java. In case the value of the column is not NULL I am aware that I could use this code:

```
context.update(TABLENAME)
    .set(TABLENAME.COUNTER, TABLENAME.COUNTER.add(incrementValue))
    .where(TABLENAME.ID.eq(id))
    .execute();
```

however if the column value has NULL value I am wondering whether I could do something like the following by setting a default value in presence of NULL:

```
context.update(TABLENAME)
    .set(TABLENAME.COUNTER, TABLENAME.COUNTER == null ? 0 : TABLENAME.COUNTER.add(incrementValue))
    .where(TABLENAME.ID.eq(id))
    .execute();
```

Is it possible? How should I perform it?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you imagine the SQL generated for the latter statement? Probably it would be possible with a CTE, but I'm not sure whether Jooq is capable to generate it. In any case, `TABLENAME.COUNTER, TABLENAME.COUNTER == null` is likely _not_ the value of the field of the wor being updated, but an object describing the column of the table, it's never null.

Comment: I understand, that piece of code was only intended to show the kind of behavior I am looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Why doesn't your approach work?

jOOQ does not translate arbitrary Java expressions to SQL. I.e. your `TABLENAME.COUNTER == null` check is evaluated in Java prior to passing the expression to jOOQ. It will never be generated in SQL. And since `TABLENAME.COUNTER`, being generated code, will never be `null`, the conditional expression is really meaningless.

#### Solutions

You could use [`DSL.coalesce()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#coalesce-org.jooq.Field-org.jooq.Field...-) or [`DSL.nvl()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#nvl-org.jooq.Field-org.jooq.Field-) or [`DSL.ifnull()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#ifnull-org.jooq.Field-org.jooq.Field-)

```
.set(TABLENAME.COUNTER, coalesce(TABLENAME.COUNTER, inline(-1)).add(incrementValue))
```

There's also the Oracle style [`DSL.nvl2()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#nvl2-org.jooq.Field-org.jooq.Field-org.jooq.Field-) function you could use:

```
.set(TABLENAME.COUNTER, 
     nvl2(TABLENAME.COUNTER, TABLENAME.COUNTER.add(incrementValue), inline(0)))
```

Alternatively, write a [`CASE` expression](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/column-expressions/case-expressions/)

```
.set(TABLENAME.COUNTER, 
     when(TABLENAME.COUNTER.isNull(), inline(0))
     .otherwise(TABLENAME.COUNTER.add(incrementValue)))
```

As always, the above is assuming you have the following static import:

```
import static org.jooq.impl.DSL.*;
```