# JOOQ: Case Expression throws error while updating column values when it is null

Tags: sql-server, groovy, hsqldb, jooq

1. I am trying to update column values when it is null using jooq, but
   its throwing ! org.hsqldb.HsqlException: user lacks privilege or
   object not found: MGAP.PERSONAL_DETAILS.EMPLOYEE_NUMBER.

   I have tried using case expression to check field is null then
   update the value.

   I have checked the following [JOOQ: Update column values on null values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52334114/jooq-update-column-values-on-null-values)
   and tried the same but it's throwing the field name not
   found.

```java
def stmt = dsl.mergeInto(PERSONAL_DETAILS)
    .using(dsl.selectOne())
    .on(PERSONAL_DETAILS.PROFILE_ID.eq(details.id))
    .whenMatchedThenUpdate()
    .set(values)
    .whenNotMatchedThenInsert()
    .set(PERSONAL_DETAILS.PROFILE_ID, details.id)
    .set(values)
    .set(PERSONAL_DETAILS.EMPLOYEE_NUMBER, when(PERSONAL_DETAILS.EMPLOYEE_NUMBER.isNull(), inline(details.employeeNumber)))
    .execute()
```

I am expecting the value should be updated when column is null using case expression, but its throwing exception that column is not
    found.

```
 >ERROR [2019-08-30 06:19:17,333] io.crnk.core.engine.internal.http.JsonApiRequestProcessor: failed to
    process request ! org.hsqldb.HsqlException: user lacks privilege or
    object not found: MGAP.PERSONAL_DETAILS.EMPLOYEE_NUMBER ! at
    org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source) ! at
    org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source) ! at
    org.hsqldb.ExpressionColumn.checkColumnsResolved(Unknown Source) !
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDML.compileMergeStatement(Unknown Source) ! at
    org.hsqldb.ParserCommand.compilePart(Unknown Source) ! at
    org.hsqldb.ParserCommand.compileStatement(Unknown Source) ! at
    org.hsqldb.Session.compileStatement(Unknown Source) ! at
    org.hsqldb.StatementManager.compile(Unknown Source) ! at
    org.hsqldb.Session.execute(Unknown Source) ! ... 131 common frames
    omitted ! Causing: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: user lacks
    privilege or object not found: MGAP.PERSONAL_DETAILS.EMPLOYEE_NUMBER
    in statement [merge into "MGAP"."PERSONAL_DETAILS" using (select 1
    as "one" from (select 1 as dual from information_schema.system_users
    limit 1) as dual) on "MGAP"."PERSONAL_DETAILS"."PROFILE_ID" = cast(?
    as varchar(32672)) when matched then update set
    "MGAP"."PERSONAL_DETAILS"."COST_CENTRE" = cast(? as varchar(32672)),
    "MGAP"."PERSONAL_DETAILS"."COUNTRY_OF_RESIDENCE_ID" = cast(? as
    varchar(32672)), "MGAP"."PERSONAL_DETAILS"."PHONE_NUMBER" = cast(?
    as varchar(32672)), "MGAP"."PERSONAL_DETAILS"."PROFILE_ID" = cast(?
    as varchar(32672)),
    "MGAP"."PERSONAL_DETAILS"."STATE_OF_RESIDENCE_ID" = cast(? as
    varchar(32672)), "MGAP"."PERSONAL_DETAILS"."FIRST_NAME" = cast(? as
    varchar(32672)), "MGAP"."PERSONAL_DETAILS"."LAST_NAME" = cast(? as
    varchar(32672)), "MGAP"."PERSONAL_DETAILS"."EMAIL" = cast(? as
    varchar(32672)), "MGAP"."PERSONAL_DETAILS"."CLIENT_ID" = cast(? as
    varchar(32672)), "MGAP"."PERSONAL_DETAILS"."COUNTRY_OF_EMPLOYMENT" =
    cast(? as varchar(32672)) when not matched then insert
    ("PROFILE_ID", "COST_CENTRE", "COUNTRY_OF_RESIDENCE_ID",
    "PHONE_NUMBER", "STATE_OF_RESIDENCE_ID", "FIRST_NAME", "LAST_NAME",
    "EMAIL", "CLIENT_ID", "COUNTRY_OF_EMPLOYMENT", "EMPLOYEE_NUMBER")
    values (cast(? as varchar(32672)), cast(? as varchar(32672)), cast(?
    as varchar(32672)), cast(? as varchar(32672)), cast(? as
    varchar(32672)), cast(? as varchar(32672)), cast(? as
    varchar(32672)), cast(? as varchar(32672)), cast(? as
    varchar(32672)), cast(? as varchar(32672)), case
    "MGAP"."PERSONAL_DETAILS"."EMPLOYEE_NUMBER" when cast(? as
    varchar(32672)) then '12345' end)] ! at
    org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source) ! at
    org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source) ! at
    org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCPreparedStatement.<init>(Unknown Source) ! at
    org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCConnection.prepareStatement(Unknown Source) ! at
    com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection.prepareStatement(ProxyConnection.java:318)
    ! at
    com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyConnection.prepareStatement(HikariProxyConnection.java)
```

SQL i have printed from stmt:

```sql
merge into "MGAP"."PERSONAL_DETAILS" using    (
        select 1 as "one"
        from (select 1 as dual from information_schema.system_users limit 1) as dual   ) on "MGAP"."PERSONAL_DETAILS"."PROFILE_ID" =
    '528b2ac2-aa9c-45e1-88d4-959b53bc7dd0' when matched then update set 
    "MGAP"."PERSONAL_DETAILS"."COST_CENTRE" = 'IN',   
    "MGAP"."PERSONAL_DETAILS"."COUNTRY_OF_RESIDENCE_ID" = 'IN',   
    "MGAP"."PERSONAL_DETAILS"."PHONE_NUMBER" = '1212121212',   
    "MGAP"."PERSONAL_DETAILS"."PROFILE_ID" =
    '528b2ac2-aa9c-45e1-88d4-959b53bc7dd0',   
    "MGAP"."PERSONAL_DETAILS"."STATE_OF_RESIDENCE_ID" = '',   
    "MGAP"."PERSONAL_DETAILS"."FIRST_NAME" = 'test',   
    "MGAP"."PERSONAL_DETAILS"."LAST_NAME" = 'test',   
    "MGAP"."PERSONAL_DETAILS"."EMAIL" = 'user1@connect.dev',   
    "MGAP"."PERSONAL_DETAILS"."CLIENT_ID" = 'TEST',   
    "MGAP"."PERSONAL_DETAILS"."COUNTRY_OF_EMPLOYMENT" = 'IN' when not
    matched then insert (   "PROFILE_ID",    "COST_CENTRE",   
    "COUNTRY_OF_RESIDENCE_ID",    "PHONE_NUMBER",   
    "STATE_OF_RESIDENCE_ID",    "FIRST_NAME",    "LAST_NAME",   
    "EMAIL",    "CLIENT_ID",    "COUNTRY_OF_EMPLOYMENT",   
    "EMPLOYEE_NUMBER" ) values (  
    '528b2ac2-aa9c-45e1-88d4-959b53bc7dd0',    'IN',    'IN',   
    '1212121212',    '',    'Dean',    'Dorsey',   
    'user1@connect.ey.dev',    'EYBT',    'IN',    case
    "MGAP"."PERSONAL_DETAILS"."EMPLOYEE_NUMBER"
        when null then '12345' end )
```

Comment: Can you use a SQL client to make sure the column `MGAP.PERSONAL_DETAILS.EMPLOYEE_NUMBER` indeed exists in your DB? The error message indicates it might not exist.

Comment: Your use of whenMatchedThen... and whenNotMatchedThen... looks strange. You probably want to swap the actions.

Comment: @knutwannheden Yes it exists. When you pass value for that column without any case it works fine.

Comment: @fredt After select condition using primary key we need to check for whenMatchedThen first then only whenNotMatchedThen. I have tried swapping it gives compilation error like cannot resolve symbol whenMatchedThen.

Comment: I mean switch the actions after whenMatched... and whenNotMatched... because you want to UPDATE the existing values in the table and this kind of action can happen with whenMatched.. only. The whenNotMatched... is for INSERTing a new row.

Comment: Doing some testing against a HSQLDB database I believe HSQLDB doesn't support referencing the target table's columns in the `INSERT ... VALUES` clause. Please note that this is not a limitation of jOOQ but of HSQLDB itself.

Comment: I agree with @fredt that your `CASE` expression does not make sense in the `INSERT` part of the merge statement. It was probably meant to go in the `UPDATE` part. Side-note: The jOOQ code and generated SQL strings don't match. In the SQL string, you've used a different type of `CASE` expression...

Comment: @fredt I have switched as per your suggestion now its not throwing any exeption but it is storing null against the EMPLOYEE_NUMBER field which is already having value. Scenario is : EMPLOYEE_NUMBER holding value '12345', when we update the table with CASE expression it storing null against EMPLOYEE_NUMBER.

Comment: I have used coalesce(field, value) and it solved the issue. Thank you all.